# What is the process for getting paid apps into the Ubuntu Software Center? 

Tags: software-center, canonical, paid-applications

What is the process for getting paid apps into the Ubuntu Software Center?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paid (and open source) applications can be submitted to:

- [My Apps](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com) in the [Ubuntu App Developer site](http://developer.ubuntu.com)
- Learn more about [publishing apps](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/)
- Read the [commercial software FAQs](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/publish/other-forms-of-submitting-apps/commercial-software-faqs/)

Comment: The last two links here are broken.

Answer (score 3):

Canonical offers two services for commercial apps, simplified very basically here:

1. The **Full-service option** where they do all the work to put the program in the Software Centre
2. The **Self-service option** where you package it, and they give you feedback, and put it in the Software Centre

For more details see the Canonical website [page on Application Packaging](http://www.canonical.com/engineering-services/certification/application-packaging).

I assume this is the only way to get software into the store. I also imagine both services are currently more expensive than say putting software in the iOS market. On the other hand I'm sure Canonical offer reasonable prices - I just think they're trying to attract businesses rather than individuals at the moment.

Certainly it is possible for applications to be added 'mid-release'.

Comment: It's roughly 29 minutes into the video.

Answer (score 1):

All apps for the Software Center can be submitted to http://software-center.ubuntu.com/dev now - and it will accept apps that require activation/license keys now for Ubuntu 11.10, too!