# Where are the guidelines for the Software Center approval process for paid applications?

Tags: software-center, paid-applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Paid apps in the Ubuntu Software Center](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8241/paid-apps-in-the-ubuntu-software-center)

On every post on Ubuntu Gamer, the first reaction of people is always

> When will this come to software center?

Are there any guidelines available on the Ubuntu Wiki already or they are being worked on?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this.

http://www.canonical.com/engineering-services/certification/application-packaging

Thanks
chris