# How to include applications/software in Canonical Partners repo?

Tags: software-center, packaging, software-sources, canonical, official-repositories

There seems to be *no publicly* documented information about how to get applications included in the **Canonical Partners** repo.

- How does an app/software get included there?
- What are the benefits?
- Do apps need to pay Canonical for inclusion in that repo? (if so, all the app dev needs to do is just pay for the service, no matter what the standard/popularity/usefulness of the app is, it gets included?)

> Note: this is about applications in
>   **http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu** repo and *not the Independent
>   repo* (http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) which falls under the App Review Process.

Answer (score 3):

Canonical offers two services for commercial apps, simplified very basically here:

1. The **Full-service option** where they do all the work to put the program in the Software Centre
2. The **Self-service option** where you package it, and they give you feedback, and put it in the Software Centre

For more details see the Canonical's [page on Application Packaging](http://www.canonical.com/engineering-services/certification/application-packaging).

Comment: part of this question here, was [answered](http://askubuntu.com/questions/8241/paid-apps-in-the-ubuntu-software-center/8308#8308) in a different question.

Comment: this question is often asked by several Ubuntu folk, but not many seem to find the above Canonical link since the page does not have any reference to "Canonical Partners" or the repo name mentioned and hence, Google doesnt seem to help..