# How to submit commercial apps to the Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center, application-development, paid-applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the process for getting paid apps into the Ubuntu Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8241/what-is-the-process-for-getting-paid-apps-into-the-ubuntu-software-center)

Why isn't there a clear description for developers on selling an app on the Ubuntu Software Center? I was thinking of maybe tying it up to the ubuntu one account for integrating the app with cloud services.

Answer (score 6):

You'll find all the information you need on the [Ubuntu App Developer](http://developer.ubuntu.com) site:

- [How to submit and publish apps](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/)
- [FAQ for commercial software](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/publish/other-forms-of-submitting-apps/commercial-software-faqs/)

Comment: None of these links work.